# How to check for a value across columns and then copy the the contents of one cell below it?

Tags: excel, vba

So I have an excel sheet with the days of the week starting at D7 and extending to AF7 for 15 days of the month. I want to look through each of them and then copy the contents of the cell directly below them in row 8 to another sheet.

Im getting runtime error 1004 Method Range of Object _Global failed on this line. Im pretty new to VBA so I'm not exactly sure what went wrong.

```
LastCol = Range(Cells(7, Columns.Count)).End(xlUp).Columns
```

Full code:

```
Sub Copy()
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long

    LastCol = Range(Cells(7, Columns.Count)).End(xlUp).Columns
    i = 4

    For Each cell In Sheets(1).Range(LastCol & "D7:7")
        If cell.Value = "MON" Then
            cell.Offset(-1, 0).Copy Sheets(2).Cells(1, i)
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the last, that is rightmost, column in a row, first set MyRow to the row you want to use:

```
lastcol= ActiveSheet.Cells(MyRow, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
```

For the last row, after setting MyColumn to the appropriate value:

```
lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, MyColumn).End(xlUp).Row
```

But your range reference isn't quite right either.  Personally, I don't see the value of using a range variable in the loop.  You could try this.  (note that a negative offset reads the row above, not below)

```
Sub Copy()
Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long, LocX as long
Dim source As Worksheet, dest As Worksheet
Set source = Sheets(1)
Set dest = Sheets(2)
lastcol = source.Cells(7, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
i = 4
For locX = 4 To lastcol
    If source.Cells(7, locX).Value = "mon" Then
        source.Cells(7, locX).Offset(1, 0).Copy dest.Cells(1, i)
        i = i + 1
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. This works wonderfully with a little tweaking to get just the cell values.

Answer (score 0):

The name you've assigned to *LastCol* seems to indicate that you want to get the column number yet you are using `xlUp` instead of `xlToLeft`. Additionally, you are asking for the `.Columns`, not the `Column`.

```
LastCol = Cells(7, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
```

This returns the column number (e.g. column F = 6, column AA = 27, etc) of the last used column in row 7.

```
with Sheets(1)
    LastCol = .Cells(7, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    For Each cell In .cells(7, "D").resize(1, LastCol - 3)
        If ucase(cell.Value) = "MON" Then
            cell.Offset(1, 0).Copy destination:=Sheets(2).Cells(1, i)
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next
end with
```

1. Are you using an actual date in row 7 with a custom number format of *ddd*? If this is the case, then you should be using `If weekday(cell.Value) = 2 Then` instead of checking for *MON*.
2. If you want to *copy the contents of the cell directly below them* then your offset should be 1 row not -1 row; e.g. `cell.Offset(1, 0).Copy`

Comment: Just what exactly is the difference between .columns and .column? 
MSDN wasn't exactly clear on that, and I didn't notice that in their examples that .column was used only at the end of lines.

Comment: Try [Range.Column Property (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff198200.aspx) and [Range.Columns Property (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837125.aspx).  On a worksheet it is like the difference between `=COLUMN(A"A)` which returns an integer and `=COLUMNS(A"A)` which returns a cell range amounting to the cells in column A. You do not use `COUNTIF(COLUMN(A:A), "abc")` that is like saying `COUNTIF(1, "abc")` but you do use `COUNTIF(COLUMNS(A:A), "abc")` to find out how many cells contain *abc* in column A.